# react-owl-carousel2 breaks after navigating away and returning to page

Tags: reactjs, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I am new to React. I am using https://github.com/florinn/react-owl-carousel2 on my homepage. So if i go to some other page and returns back to homepage my owl-carousel is not working and its coming broken. So how can i reinitialise so that it triggers when i am back to homepage.

```
import OwlCarousel from 'react-owl-carousel2';

    const options = {
                items: 3,
                rewind: false,
                autoplay: false,
                stagePadding:20,
                responsive:{
                    0:{
                        items:2,
                    },
                }

            };



<OwlCarousel  options={options} > 

<div></div>
</OwlCarousel>
```

Comment: Could you include a bit more of your code? It's unclear exactly where these code fragments are in your code: Which parts are in components, the type of components you are using, the general structure of your app, etc.

Comment: Also, if you could describe more precisely how the carousel is broken and exactly what steps led to that state, that would be useful. Logs and/or screenshots might make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement it using `useEffect()` hook or `componentDidMount()` to accomplish your task.

Comment: Im using it first time so i dont know how to do it. Can you share how to implement it.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-owl-carousel-in-reactjs use this link for basic installation.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-owl-carousel-in-reactjs use this link for basic installation. Then     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 use this link for index.html instead of given link in the blog I have shared with you in the public folder. It will work. Let me know if you need any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

Kindly follow the steps.

1. create-react-app sample.
2. yarn add react-owl-carousel
3. yarn start

Here I hope your react app is up and running.
[React Js OwlCarousel Demonstration Article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-owl-carousel-in-reactjs)

Follow this article.
*Don't leave your div tags blank*

```
<OwlCarousel  options={options} > 
<div></div>
</OwlCarousel>
```

Follow the steps above and let me know if it is working or not.
Here I have used OwlCarousel not OwlCarousel2

Comment: Hi. I have done passing options.First time on pageload it works properly.  But what happens is when i go to another page and comes back it it not triggering owl carousel . The owl carousel is not getting initiated. Hence it breaks the whole page. This is the issue i am facing